# Basic ternary to if/then conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Would someone mind converting this line of ternary code to `if`/`then` statements. I understand ternary, but am not able to get syntax errors to go away when I convert to `if`/`then`. This is the only line of my homework I had to borrow and I'd like to make it into `if`/`then` so that I can comment on it and understand it better myself.

Original:

```
return n == null || isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
```

My attempt:

```
return n == null || if(isNaN(n)){return 0;}else{return n;}
```

Comment: Thanks gosh there is no stackoverflow for surgeons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the `return` and have a separate one for the if and the else:

```
if(n == null || isNaN(n)){
    return 0;
}else{
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Selected as correct answer since you answered first! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n == null || isNaN(n)) {
  return 0;
} else {
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n == null || isNaN(n))
    return 0;
else 
    return n;
```

Comment: `!n` isn't the same as `n == null`

Comment: What about the null value? Is that implied or does it need to be added somehwere?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think it is doing:

```
if (n == null || isNan(n))
   return 0;
else
   return n;
```

The `||` operator has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the `?` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply some [grammatics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/#Statements) here:

- The original line is a statement: the [return keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) with a expression, consisting of a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- The expected result should be a [if-else statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else): Blocks of conditional executed statements - return statements.

The other four answers present the correct source code, I don't want to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that return must be the first statement on any line it appears (as per the ECMA specs).

The code is easier to translate if you first add parentheses ( `n == null || (isNaN(n) ? 0 : n)` gives different results and is not equivalent to javascript's default parsing of un-parenthesesed code)

```
return (n == null || isNaN(n)) ? 0 : n;
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (n == null || isNaN(n)) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return n;
}
```

Comment: What would these added parenthesis change?